# Query on scope of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, python

If i run below python code,

```
def f():
    return bar

foo = f
foo()
bar = 3
foo()
```

as `python file.py` Then this code will be in scope of `__main__` module of python interpreter.

On similar lines, I would like to know, What is the  scope of below JavaScript code?

```
var foo = function(){
    return bar;
};

foo();
var bar = 3;
foo();
```

Is JavaScript code loaded as module similar to python interpreter Environment?

Comment: Sham read [Global variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) from mozilla.org probability your will get answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the scope of below JavaScript code?

This depends on the environment.

For client-side JavaScript, the snippet will be executed directly within the global scope, making `foo` and `bar` globals and properties of the global object, `window`.

```
var foo = 'bar';

console.log('foo' in window); // true
console.log(window.foo, foo); // 'bar' 'bar'
```

Though, other environments have implemented module specifications, such as those from [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS), and may define that each script file be given its own scope.

```
var foo = 'bar';

console.log('foo' in global); // false

exports.foo = foo; // make available to other modules
```

Comment: I would like to see what are all the properties of global object window that are visible to my javaScript code. How can i do that in javascript? In python i know my scope of my module by calling globals()

Comment: @Sham In [ES5-compatible browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames#Specifications), you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). Otherwise, you can at least iterate enumerable properties with [`for (var key in window)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: jonathan if i need to learn javascript and run the above method that you recommended, then Do i need to use html with it, can't we run javascript code just like we run python using interprester? i mean without html code? Becasue i have not written javascript everbefore and i want to learn javasscript as language first and then think of using javascript(in browser) later. How can i do that? Can you direct me some resources on this?

Comment: jonathan Do you think my question make sense in my previous update? I would like to chat with you, to understand the approach of introspecting how my javascript code sits in the scope of window object?

Answer (score 0):

With Javascripts `variable hosting`, your code will execute as if written this way:

```
var bar;
var foo;

foo = function(){
      return bar;
};

foo();

bar = 3;

foo();
```

and, as written, this will all run within the global scope, creating the variables `foo` and `bar` at the global level.

Comment: No I had written same answer (now deleted) He is asking something else.